# What is success url & failure url while integrating payU Money in android?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payumoney

Here is my some activity code, what will be the surl & furl? could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance :)

```
 Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

            mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
            mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
            mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
            mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
            mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
            mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
            mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
            mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
            mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
            mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
            mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

             System.out.println("mapParams=="+mapParams);

            webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());
```

Comment: What error are you getting??Explain your problem little more.

Comment: confusion on surl and furl? what is this two urls and from where i could get and pass this?

Comment: Did the below answer help you??

Answer (score 2):

The following diagram explains how the customer makes the payment and how the process flows:

[image]

**Step 1:** The consumer selects the product on your website and clicks on “Pay Now” button.

**Step 2:** The consumer is then taken from your website to the transaction page of www.payumoney.com where in all the payment related details are entered by the consumer.

**Step 3:** Payumoney.com.com redirects the consumer to Visa, MasterCard or the relevant bank for the next level of authorization.

**Step 4:** The Bank/Visa/MasterCard authorizes and confirms the transaction.

**Step 5:** The consumer is sent back to PayUMoney.

**Step 6:** PayUMoney sends the consumer back to your website along with the transaction status.

The `surl` and `furl` comes into picture in the last step of the above flow. It is just the Success and Failure page URL, where you wish to take your user on success and failure cases.

For example if you have a Thank You page where you want the user to go after successful transaction then you pass the URL of that page as `surl`.

Similarly, if you have any error page where you want to take user on failure then pass that URL as `furl`.

**Source:** [PayUMoney Integration in android.](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2015/10/payumoney-integration-in-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

payumoney post user and transaction data to these `urls`. all success transaction goes to surl and all failed transaction data go to furl as a post request.

you can save these information for your application logic.

[here](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/4.-Server-Side#return-url---surl--furl) is the link which shows POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Success & Failure URI are a redirection link. Basically, when the transaction is successful, then it will redirect to success URI else it will redirect to failure URI.

Answer (score 0):

In PayuMoney builder variable you need to set these parameters where success an failure URL also mention.

```
  builder.setAmount(amount)                          // Payment amount
                .setTxnId(txnid)                     // Transaction ID
                .setPhone(phone)                   // User Phone number
                .setProductName(prodname)                   // Product Name or description
                .setFirstName(firstname)                              // User First name
                .setEmail(email)              // User Email ID
                .setsUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php")     // Success URL (surl)
                .setfUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php")     //Failure URL (furl)
                .setUdf1("")
                .setUdf2("")
                .setUdf3("")
                .setUdf4("")
                .setUdf5("")
                .setUdf6("")
                .setUdf7("")
                .setUdf8("")
                .setUdf9("")
                .setUdf10("")
                .setIsDebug(true)                              // Integration environment - true (Debug)/ false(Production)
                .setKey(merchantkey)                        // Merchant key
                .setMerchantId(merchantId);
```

You can find complete  [Downloadable tutorial with working app in this link](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration/).
PayUmoney has very simple integration process. Steps are as below-

**Step 1** get merchant key and salt

**Step 2** upload server side PHP files for checksum HASH

**Step 3** add dependency

**Step 4** get checksum hash

**Step 5** start transactions

Answer (score 0):

When making a payment using the PayUmoney Android SDK gives two types of payment response:

**1. A client-side response in the callback function**

**2. A server to server callback on the Webhook, if set from the PayUmoney dashboard.**

1. Client side response handling :
   To know when the payment has completed, override the onActivityResult in your activity as exemplified in the sample code below

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result Code is -1 send from Payumoney activity
    Log.d("MainActivity", "request code " + requestCode + " resultcode " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == PayUmoneyFlowManager.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        TransactionResponse transactionResponse = data.getParcelableExtra( PayUmoneyFlowManager.INTENT_EXTRA_TRANSACTION_RESPONSE );

        if (transactionResponse != null && transactionResponse.getPayuResponse() != null) {

            if(transactionResponse.getTransactionStatus().equals( TransactionResponse.TransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL )){
                //Success Transaction
            } else{
                //Failure Transaction
            }

            // Response from Payumoney
            String payuResponse = transactionResponse.getPayuResponse();

            // Response from SURl and FURL
            String merchantResponse = transactionResponse.getTransactionDetails();
        }  else if (resultModel != null && resultModel.getError() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error response : " + resultModel.getError().getTransactionResponse());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Both objects are null!");
        }
    }
}
```

2. Server side response handling:

At your service to handle the payu success and failure responses.

For Example (REST):

SURL: https://hostname/REST/service/payusucess

FURL: https://hostname/REST/service/payufailure

When a payment was done, it will POST a response to your server side corresponding(success/failure). Your have to get the response and handle it in your REST service and display the response page.